# AsyncAppender in log4j.properties file

Tags: properties, log4j, asyncappender

I'm having some trouble with this, and even though I've searched for an answer, couldn't find it yet.

I've seen a lot of different log4j configurations in order to use the **AsyncAppender**, anyway, none of them was related to a .properties configuration file.

I've tried different configurations on my own, but no success at all when trying to use the asyncAppender with a SocketAppender.

Can the AsyncAppender be configured on the .properties file, or does it need to be configured by code/xml configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: no, there's no way to configure it via properties file.

AsyncAppender needs to be configured by code/xml.

: )

Comment: And how do you do it by code? All I can find is via XML

Comment: @DavidBrossard I'm a bit late (a year or so), just read it. I mean something like the second example on this link: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender